# Formulate data for rpart

Tags: r, rpart, cart-analysis

Concatenate columns name of a list to prepare a formula for `rpart`?

Just wanted to concatenate the names(log_data), `log_data` is a list of 60 vectors distinct vectors, so I just want their column names in a format so that I can put them in a formula of rpart in r..... like `rpart(A ~ B + C + D + E ,log_data)`, so here I just want to extract
formula="A~B+C+D+E" as a whole string where A,B,C,D,E are the columns name which we have to extract from the log_data, or is there any better way to get a tree from the list.
I have tried,

```
a <- names(log_data)  
rpart(a[1] ~ a[2] + a[3] + a[4], log_data)
```

getting an error

```
Error in paste(temp, yprob[, i], sep = " ") : subscript out of bounds
```

where

```
a[2]

[1] "X.u.crpice..vin20f1..vol.vin20f1v1.r_credit_credshare2...91...90."

a[3]

[1] "X.u.crpice..vin20f1..vol.vin20f1v1.r_credit_credshare2...92...90."

c<-paste(a[1], "~", sep="")

rpart_formula <- as.formula(paste(c, paste(a[2:60], collapse = " + "), sep = ""))

rpart(rpart_formula,log_data)
```

it is going in infinite loop at rpart just because of too long column name or may be n=60

Can I attach any column names **colnames(log_data) <- c(?)**, what should I put at "?", so that will be easy to draw it for n=60.

Comment: `o(1)`? I assume you mean `O(1)`

Comment: yes sir but it will be ohkk if i get any suitable method too ,to implement it .

Comment: does your new solution work OK for a smaller set of predictors?  At what length does it break down?   Does `rpart(response~.,data=log_data)` work?  (How do you know it's in an infinite loop and not just taking a long time?)

Comment: yes it is working fine if i take the column name small by length and small snumber of column name in r formula

Comment: actually i want to replace the large column name of file with order characters. so that there will be no array bound problem.thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you want

```
shortnames <- paste0("c",seq(ncol(log_data)))
names(log_data) <- shortnames
form <- reformulate(paste(shortnames[2:4],collapse="+"),
                    response=shortnames[1])
rpart(form,log_data)
```

Comment: sir i got this but this is going in infinite loop ,i have implemeted this alsoc<-paste(a[1], "~", sep="")
rpart_formula <- as.formula(paste(c, paste(a[2:60], collapse = " + "), sep = ""))

Comment: hard to say what's going wrong without a reproducible example.  Does your alternative solution also fail, or did that work?

Comment: nope it did not may be just because of error due to array bound and unable to change the column names as in integer as well

Comment: if this works for you, would you accept it?  If you came up with your own solution, you can post it as an answer (it's acceptable to answer your own question ...)

Comment: dont know what was the exact problem but when i restart again it was working fine ,thank you sir .